# Sort a Map with a custom comparator in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
final_map = ["/7amd64-Aug2022.1":"2022-08-09","/7amd64-Oct2022.1":"2022-10-12","/7":"2022-11-08","/7amd64-Jul2022.1":"2022-07-12","/7amd64":"2022-11-08","/7amd64-June2022.1":"2022-06-14","/7amd64-beta":"2022-11-08","/7amd64-Sep2022.1":"2022-09-14","/7amd64-Nov2022.1":"2022-11-08","/_uploads":"2022-11-08"]
```

Jenkins Pipeline (below is the code I have, which is not working)

```
result = final_map.sort { a,b -> a.value <=> b.value }
echo "Output: ${result}"
```

Expecting to sort the map with date (value).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom comparator for this. Check the following Groovy code.

```
final_map = ["/7amd64-Aug2022.1":"2022-08-09","/7amd64-Oct2022.1":"2022-10-12","/7":"2022-11-08","/7amd64-Jul2022.1":"2022-07-12","/7amd64":"2022-11-08","/7amd64-June2022.1":"2022-06-14","/7amd64-beta":"2022-11-08","/7amd64-Sep2022.1":"2022-09-14","/7amd64-Nov2022.1":"2022-11-08","/_uploads":"2022-11-08"]

final_map.sort { s1, s2 -> 

        def s1Date = new Date(s1.value.replace('-', '/'))
        def s2Date = new Date(s2.value.replace('-', '/'))
 
        if( s1Date.before(s2Date)) {
            return -1
        } else {
            return 1
        } 
    }
println final_map
```